# How to get recently added files from Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Is there anyway to get the newly added files from Amazon S3 (like sort by timestamp or something)? My current approach is to go through each file and compare their creation timestamp, and it is very slow when i have lots of files in the bucket.

Comment: How, specifically, do you "go through each file?"  You can fetch lists of objects 1000 at a time, which includes S3's timestamp.  Is that what you're already doing?

Comment: No, i was using a hadoop api for the job, so everytime i need to check the timestamp it was sort of making a call to S3 to retrieve the property. I Moved to AWS SDK, now it seems working fine.